# Unable to launch web browser flex

Tags: apache-flex, firefox, flex4, browser, flexbuilder

I AM Using Flex Builder 4 for flex Web application, In which I create one flex Web Application. Now i am trying to run my application on web browser at that time builder shows some error like **(Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe": CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied)**.

This error shows me from last one day. So will anyone can give me answer that why i got such error. In preferences Default System Web browser is selected. which is Mozilla Firefox.

Thanks

Comment: Can you manually launch firefox and is it working ?

Comment: Yes manually it is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just clean and close flash builder project. And then close flash builder and restart my system and then relaunch flash builder then it will works now.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Window -> Preferences -> General -> Web Browser. There you can see the available browsers listed and a radio button for selecting either the internal or external browser. Do check these settings and try to launch again. It may be that the path you have shown, where "firefox.exe" resides has not been updated within the Flash Builder.

Answer (score 0):

Rigth click on the flashbuilder shortcut -> run as administrator

Answer (score 0):

If you can't run as an admin, try checking on the security settings to ensure all users have full access to the Firefox directory & files.  This almost has to be security related, unless Firefox is actually a location different from where it's looking.